# How do I create tile-maps in PyGame without download?

Tags: python

I wanted to create tile-maps for my game to take up less space on my computer. I really don't have much space. I don't want to download an app to do the job for me, also for the fact that I don't have much space. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: are you talking about not downloading Pygame?

Comment: what have you tried so ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some tools online and [github projects](https://github.com/collections/pixel-art-tools) about this. You could use https://www.piskelapp.com/ which seems to be pretty nice, otherwise you could search for a light application that satisfice your requirements over github...